# Build a front-end web

Tags: java, wordpress, tomcat, web, frontend

We are currently working on a project which includes Mobile Apps and a front-end website. The backend server has already been built and running as Java Application under Tomat, which support all the APIs.

I am wondering, if a front-end website could be built under same domain or across domain, and calling the same APIs from the backend server? like what Mobile App does?

By the way, all the front-end does not need to communicate with database, the data will be retrieved through server APIs.

I only done mobile apps, and a web greener, if there is anything misunderstanding, please comment, thanks:)

**Update**
Is it possible to use WordPress or Drupal to build this front-end website? or should I built myself with pure html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering, if a front-end website could be built under same domain or across domain, and calling the same APIs from the backend server? like what Mobile App does?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer:

- Provided that the front-end web pages don't include or generate any URLs that refer to the backend site, there should be no cross-site issues.  If possible, this is the architecture you should aim for.
- If you do need the front-end web pages to include backend URLs<sup>1</sup>, then there are ways to deal with this ... is the user's web browser supports the relevant technologies; e.g. CORS.

---

<sup>1 - ... and the browser needs to be able to resolve / fetch them.</sup>

Comment: Thanks~ I use ajax to handle the api calls, and so far, there is no problem. But I was wondering if the website could be built with WordPress or Drupal framework?

Comment: Yea, sure it could.  Modulo the caveats above.  (I don't know enough about either of those frameworks to say whether it would be a good idea though.  It probably depends a lot on what the site does and should look like.  Personally, I'd look at a wider range of options ... but it depends on what you are familiar with.)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen C :) I will try with WordPress firstly and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

If the backend is exposed as webservices, a front end webapp can call those services via ajax if they are in the same domain. If they are cross domain, it gets a little trickier because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (there are techniques like JSONP and CORS to help with that).

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I have made a test website and put it under the tomcat, and using ajax to handle all the api calls, so far, it works.